# Segment a dynamic IPv6 range

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

My ISP gives me a /60 IPv6 range through DHCP6. The range is dynamic (i.e. changes on each restart of the router). I'd like to setup an incoming VPN server on the router (running OpenWRT). I'd like to segment the /60 range into two sub-segments, one for the local machines and one for the VPN. Unfortunately I can't hardcode the network addresses because they change on every restart. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: That's called *prefix delegation* - unfortunately, I haven't seen a consumer grade router for that yet...

Comment: I think you should go back to your isp and tell them not to be so stupid. That net give you 16 potential subnets. It is wholly ludicrous to expect end users to have to renumber them each and every time the connection is restarted.

Comment: The router is running OpenWRT so I can run whatever software is necessary for that. I'm not sure about VPN connections though because OpenVPN handles that and I don't think it supports dynamic delegations.

Talking to the ISP is like talking to a robot wearing human clothes. Can't expect much from them.